# CONSULTA SQL - POSTGRES REGISTRO REPETIDO POR UNA SOLA COLUMNA

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo una tabla que tiene unos puntajes de estudiantes:

**Codigo | prueba | puntaje**

123456 | p00001 | 3.2 |

123456 | p00002 | 1.0 |

123456 | p00003 | 5.0 |

Y quiero sacar en consulta

**123456 | p00001 | 3.2 | p00002 | 1.0 | p00003 | 5.0 |**

Comment: ¿Cual es la lógica de tu resultado deseado? ¿Y es posible tener un número variable de registros? En ese caso, ¿cual es el resultado deseado? Y la pregunta más importante: ¿qué has intentado hasta ahora?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas soluciones son válidas mientras se maneje un número razonable de pruebas, sino la consulta se complejiza mucho.

```
-- Usando múltiples LEFT JOINS
select  T.codigo, 
        T1.prueba,
        T1.puntaje "Puntaje_p00001",
        T2.prueba,
        T2.puntaje "Puntaje_p00002",
        T3.prueba,
        T3.puntaje "Puntaje_p00003"
        from temporal T
        LEFT JOIN temporal T1
            ON T1.codigo = T.codigo
            AND T1.prueba = 'p00001'
        LEFT JOIN temporal T2
            ON T2.codigo = T.codigo
            AND T2.prueba = 'p00002'
        LEFT JOIN temporal T3
            ON T3.codigo = T.codigo
            AND T3.prueba = 'p00003'
        GROUP BY  T.codigo, 
                  T1.prueba,
                  T1.puntaje,
                  T2.prueba,
                  T2.puntaje,
                  T3.prueba,
                  T3.puntaje

;
-- Usando la función agregada MAX (es la idea de @Ric_hc)
select  codigo,
        MAX(CASE WHEN prueba = 'p00001' THEN 'p00001' ELSE NULL END) "prueba",
        MAX(CASE WHEN prueba = 'p00001' THEN puntaje ELSE NULL END) "Puntaje_p00001",
        MAX(CASE WHEN prueba = 'p00002' THEN 'p00002' ELSE NULL END) "prueba",
        MAX(CASE WHEN prueba = 'p00002' THEN puntaje ELSE NULL END) "Puntaje_p00002",
        MAX(CASE WHEN prueba = 'p00003' THEN 'p00003' ELSE NULL END) "prueba",
        MAX(CASE WHEN prueba = 'p00003' THEN puntaje ELSE NULL END) "Puntaje_p00003"
        from temporal
        GROUP BY codigo
;
```

En casos más complejos tal vez lo mejor es apuntar a una transposición de filas por columnas, te sugiero que veas [este](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084503/postgresql-convert-columns-to-rows-transpose) enlace que esta muy bien documentada la forma de hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Mira te brindo una solución, tal vez sea una forma de lo que necesitas. Intentalo, espero te ayude.

```
create table #temporal(
    codigo int,
    prueba varchar(6), 
    puntaje double precision
);

insert into #temporal (codigo, prueba, puntaje)
values(123456, 'p00003', 3.5 )

insert into #temporal (codigo, prueba, puntaje)
values(123456, 'p00002', 2.8 )

insert into #temporal (codigo, prueba, puntaje)
values(123456, 'p00003', 9.5 )


select codigo,
    max(case when prueba = 'p00001' then puntaje end) as [p0001],
    max(case when prueba = 'p00002' then puntaje end) as [p0002],
    max(case when prueba = 'p00003' then puntaje end) as [p0003]
from #temporal
group by codigo
```

Resultado:

```
codigo     p0001    p0002   p0003
123456      3.5      2.8     3.5
```

Anexo el link de conversión de script: http://www.sqlines.com/online

Comment: Ahhh, un momento por favor. Lo siento, se me olvido.

Comment: Lo siento, pero sigue siendo un script que no funcionaría en PostgreSQL. Una simple conversión de script no es suficiente. Hay que conocer la sintaxis. Lo mejor es probar la consulta en PostgreSQL antes de publicar la respuesta.

Comment: Uppps, tienen razón, elimino la respuesta. Gracias